# Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: symbolic-link

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TuP5.png)

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04. It's giving an error opening directory too many levels of symbolic links as shown in attachment.
I am a newbie. Please help.

Comment: A circular set of links results in that error (some link in Music linking back to Music). Pretty rare to actually have links nested to the max depth.

Comment: You must have done something other than just install it. What did you do?

Comment: Nothing else. I just installed it. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Is this a hardware issue? Please let me know.