# error opening directory too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: symbolic-link

Ubuntu 22.04. It's giving an error opening directory too many levels of symbolic links. Please help

Comment: Thanks for the information about the error! It is difficult for us to guess what might be wrong, though, based on the detail you provided.

Comment: Just guessing, due to the lack of information oin your question.  You have created a loop with your symbolic links. `a->b->a`. Rather than looping forever, when evaluating symbolic links,  the system decrements a counter and issues the error messsge when the counter reaches zero.

Comment: How do I resolve this? Please suggest.

Comment: Delete one of the links. Use `rm`.

Comment: You already asked this already!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Too many levels of symbolic links](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1482992/too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links)